# WorkStatus is BLOCKED if using unique work with chain request

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Following is the code

```
var syncItemWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncItemWorker>().addTag(SYNC_ITEM_ONE_TIME).build()

    var pullMastersWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncMasterWorker>().addTag(SYNC_MASTER_ONE_TIME).build()

    var pullLabelsWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncLabelWorker>().addTag(SYNC_LABEL_ONE_TIME).build()

    var syncMovementWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SyncMovementWorker>().addTag(SYNC_MOVEMENT_ONE_TIME).build()

 var continuation = WorkManager.getInstance().beginUniqueWork("manual_sync", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND, pullMastersWork)
                .then(pullLabelsWork)
                .then(syncMovementWork)
                .then(syncItemWork)
        continuation.enqueue()
```

> For checking status i am using following code:

```
 WorkManager.getInstance().getStatusById(syncItemWork.id).observe(this,
            Observer { status ->
                Timber.d("getStatusById:$status")
                if (status != null && status.state.isFinished) {
                    manualSync.isEnabled = true
                    GlideApp.with(this).load(R.drawable.ic_sync).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE).into(ivManualSync)

                    var lastSyncTime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity as Context).getLong(PREF_KEY_LAST_SYNC_TIME, 0),
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,
                            DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_RELATIVE
                    )
                    view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtName).text = lastSyncTime
                }
            })
```

The work is not getting enqueued and status is BLOCKED and in log it says:
**The state for work that is currently blocked because its prerequisites haven't finished successfully**

Answer (score 0):

Are any of your `Worker`s completing ?

You are using `APPEND` and thence creating a very long continuation of work. If you don't handle error conditions correctly, you are bound to end up in a state where subsequent `Worker`s are blocked on pre-requisites or they fail altogether because at some point a parent in the chain `FAILED`. Maybe you could consider using `REPLACE` instead if you want the most recent chain to execute ?